# Popup menu take some space from right

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm popup menu items which takes some space from right side. How to remove this space from right side.

[image]

Please follow screen-shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can set popup show location as well as it height and width.

Go through below code:

```
   int popupWidth = 200;
   int popupHeight = 150;


final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
   popup.setContentView(layout);
   popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
   popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
   popup.setFocusable(true);

   // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
   int OFFSET_X = 30;
   int OFFSET_Y = 30;

   // Clear the default translucent background
   popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

   // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
   popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);
```